# Is JVM threads different from tomcat thread in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, jvm, threadpool

I have an async operation in spring boot that uses cached thread pool of spring. When the http request comes in, a thread gets started which is in tomcat. In the same thread an async thread is triggered with newCachedThreadPool(). Now the question, is these two thread (tomcat thread and async thread in cachedThreadPool) are supplied by JVM ? Or JVM has it's own thread pool and tomcat has it's own?

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ThreadResource {

    private final ThreadService threadService;

    @GetMapping("/theards/async")
    public void verifyThreads() {
        threadService.asyncThread();
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ThreadService {

    private final AsycThreadService asycThreadService;
    public void asyncThread() {
        List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet());
        for (var i =0; i< 3; i++) {
            futures.add(asycThreadService.startAsyncThread());
        }
        futures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
    }
}

@Service
public class AsycThreadService {

    @Async("asyncCachedThreadPool")
    public CompletableFuture<Void> startAsyncThread() {
        System.out.println(Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet());
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }
}
```